# Error compiling liferay workspace using gradle

Tags: gradle, liferay, gradle-plugin, workspace

I'm having problems with liferay and the workspace plugin. I had to remove all gradle caches of my computer and all of a sudden the liferay project won't compile again... I execute the command:

```
./gradlew build
```

And the error I receive is:

```
* Where:
Settings file 'src/liferay/settings.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'liferay'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.liferay.workspace'.
   > Could not create an instance of type com.liferay.gradle.plugins.workspace.WorkspaceExtension.
      > com/liferay/portal/tools/bundle/support/commands/DownloadCommand
```

The settings.gradle file in those lines:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: "biz.aQute.bnd", name: "biz.aQute.bnd", version: "5.2.0"
        classpath(group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.gradle.plugins.workspace", version: "3.4.48") {
            exclude group: "biz.aQute.bnd", module: "biz.aQute.bnd"
        }
        classpath group: "net.saliman", name: "gradle-properties-plugin", version: "1.4.6"
    }

}

apply plugin: "net.saliman.properties"

apply plugin: "com.liferay.workspace"
```

The output of the command `./gradlew -v` is:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.6.1
------------------------------------------------------------

 

Build time:   2020-08-25 16:29:12 UTC
Revision:     f2d1fb54a951d8b11d25748e4711bec8d128d7e3

 

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          11.0.20 (Azul Systems, Inc. 11.0.20+8-LTS)
OS:           Linux 6.4.7-200.fc38.x86_64 amd64
```

I've tried using Java 11 (the java version I've been using for this project always) and with Java 17

I've looked for this error thought internet and I haven't seen the solution. The problem started when I clean the gradle cache, before that, the project compiled perfectly

Someone could help me?

I'm having problems compiling liferay workspace because of the lifre workspace plugin. I would like to solve my compilation problem

Answer (score 0):

Some problems have been reported due to a [changed default setting in JDK 11.0.20](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/important-jdk-11-0-20-notice) (easy to fix in runtime systems, but apparently less easily in development environments). My recommendation for now (beginning of August 2023) would be to **build with 11.0.19 max**. Note that the linked blog article with more background information has been updated a couple of times since it was initially published. TL;DR: Downgrade to 11.0.19 *for now*.

If that alone doesn't help, my settings.gradle also declare the Liferay repositories, e.g. in the `buildscript` block, after `dependencies`, add

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
    }

    maven {
        url "https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately Liferay is [not yet](https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/liferay-portal-7-4-ga87-and-liferay-commerce-4-0-ga87-release) compatible with Java 17.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I tried to downgrade java version to 11.0.19 pr 11.0.18 and it didn't work... This project is using devcontainer with VSCode and is running with Alpine container. But this can not be relevant because I tried in other computers and it works like a charm... In fact, I tried to run it in my fedora 38 (host machine) and it works too (with java 11.0.19). It seems to be a random problem...

Comment: did you add the repositories to your settings.gradle?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried with the piece of code that you've gave me and It still not working :(

Comment: What's your JDK version?

Comment: This was the output of the command "./gradlew -v":

`JVM:         11.0.20 (Azul Systems, Inc. 11.0.20+8-LTS)`

Comment: so you downgraded to 11.0.19, and your JVM tells you that its version is 11.0.20? My answer applies...

Comment: I tried to downgrade to 11.0.19 and still didn't work. When I downgraded the JVM version to 11.0.19, the `./gradlew -v` command return me JVM: 11.0.19 and didn't work

Comment: @Eryo by any chance, did you find the answer?

Comment: After downgrade to 11.0.19, it worked only after I changed distributionUrl to gradle-6.6.1-all.zip instead of gradle-6.6.1-bin.zip in gradle-wrapper.properties

Answer (score 0):

Delete .gradle folders from the project and user. Synchronize and ready the dependencies and libraries should be refreshed solving the error.

Comment: I did it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

```
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.liferay.workspace'.
    > Could not create an instance of type com.liferay.gradle.plugins.workspace.WorkspaceExtension.
        > com/liferay/portal/tools/bundle/support/commands/DownloadCommand
```

I took the following steps:

1. double checked all Jdk version configurations in IDE
2. double checked gradle version configuration
3. (re-)installed intelliJ liferay plugin and double checked version
4. double checked compatibility between all those versions
5. deleted local .gradle directory to force fresh download of all     libraries used

One thing I noticed:
I had network connectivity issues while doing this, and had to repeat step 5 to get a clean fresh download of everything.
It might be worth to redo this one.

Answer (score 0):

We had this problem turning up after we deleted our caches, e.g. setup a new system and we could reproduce it in this JVM Versions

jdk-11.0.20+8 and jdk-11.0.21.9

The only thing that  solved it for us was a downgrade to jdk-11.0.19+7

Answer (score 0):

Update the following file **gradle-wrapper.properties** properties as below.

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-all.zip